# how can i store the value from iterator to a local variable?

Tags: java, iterator

My Output is  :

```
I/System.out: Iterator values :{"name":"SMhack","permittedUsers":[1,2,3,4,5,6],"id":2,"profilesAttached":[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]}
```

i want to take the value of "id" and store it in a local variable.
how can i store the value.

My Code is :

```
Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = org.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext())
            {
                System.out.println("Iterator values :"+iterator.next());

                //here i want to store the value from iterator to be stored to a local variable named (org_id).    

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`JSONObject.getInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html#getInt-java.lang.String-) method:

```
Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = org.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    JSONObject current = iterator.next();   
    System.out.println("Iterator values : " + current);

    int orgId = current.getInt("id");

}
```

Comment: You call `iterator.next()` twice. Perhaps you should `println` the value of `current` instead.

Comment: @dave Yes, that's what I meant to do initially. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: His next question would be how to access that local variable outside the iterator loop

Comment: @JohnBupit getInt("id"); // is showing error cannot resolve method.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `org.json.simple.JSONObject` which `implements java.util.Map`. So I think you will need to do something like this:

```
Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = org.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext())
{
    JSONObject obj = iterator.next();
    int orgId = (int) obj.get("id");
    // Do something with orgId
}
```

Comment: getInt("id"); // is showing error cannot resolve method.

Comment: What JSON library are you using? Can you include the `import` statement(s) for your code, esp. those that refer to the JSON classes.

Comment: import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;